# Swift - two framework with same public structure

Tags: ios, swift

I am in a situation where i'm using two frameworks (don't have access to source code), both are from different vendors. Both framework uses same name for structure. How can i use both structure in the same code ? now since both have same class name and structure name, i am facing issue and these conflict while using it in my code.

I am using swift 4.2.
Is there anyway to use fully qualified classes/structures in swift?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use Framework1.ClassName and Framework2.ClassName. Maybe it will work.